# PanGestureRecognizer cancels UIButton Press

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have some buttons set up with PanGestureRecognizers on them, and I want to be able to still have access to TouchUpInside once I have moved my button to the desired location. However, as soon as PanGesture takes over it cancels the button's pressed state. So far I have:

```
- (IBAction)drag: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

  if (recognizer.state == (Ive tried every UIGestureRecognizerState available here)
  {
    NSLog(@"It's Working");

    [_LauncherOne setSelected:TRUE];
    [_LauncherOne setHighlighted:TRUE];
  }
```

But the recognizers aren't firing. Are they in the wrong place?

UPDATE

So this seems like its exactly what I'm looking for, but I guess I'm implementing it wrong. I put 
     " recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;  "
right after my IBAction declaration but it's not working. Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` for your recognizer.

See also in apple doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html